# Subtracting Elements in DataFrame Column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any function that allows one to subtract elements with a data frame column? For example, let's say one has the following values in a data frame column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Let's assume that 1 is element i, 2 is element i+2 and so on. How does one subtract i from i+4?

Comment: Do you want subtract just these 2? Or all rows from their 5th next row?

Comment: `i - i.shift(-4)`

Comment: All rows from their 5th next row

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')) #create random data frame 
iterate_to=df.shape[0]-4 #specify how far you'll be iterating to
#iterating further than the number of rows will cause an error
differences=[] #create a list into which the calculated differences will be put
for i in range(0,iterate_to): #iterate through the rows 1 at a time
     differences.append(df['A'][i+4]-df['A'][i]) #append the differences between i and i+4
```